# use beta distribution from mathdotnet in C# in VS2013

Tags: c#, distribution, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I ma using mathdotnet form C# in VS2013.

I need to generate a sequence of samples from

```
IEnumerable<double> Samples(double a, double b)
```

at

```
http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.Distributions/Beta.htm#Samples
```

I do not know how to control the sample size. For exmaple, I only need to get 5000 smaple points from the distribution.

This is my C# code:

```
  Beta betadistr = new Beta(alpha, beta);
  list<double> sample = betadistr.samples(alpha, beta);
```

What is the size of sample ?

And what is the difference between

```
 IEnumerable<double> Samples(double a, double b)
```

and

```
  IEnumerable<double> Samples(Random rnd, double a, double b)
```

How to use the rnd to control the sample?

Answer (score 0):

The distributions offer two ways to generate multiple samples in one go:

- `Sample()` returns an infinite sequence. Allows lazy evaluation. Take as many as you need, on demand.
- `Sample(array)` fills an array completely. Generally the fastest if the whole array is needed.

so, if you strictly need an `IList<double>` with 5000 samples, you can do either:

```
Beta beta = new Beta(alpha, beta);
List<double> samples = beta.Samples().Take(5000).ToList();
```

or

```
Beta beta = new Beta(alpha, beta);
double[] samples = new double[5000];
beta.Samples(samples);
```

If you don't actually need the `Beta` instance for anything else, you can simplify this by using the static routines, which work the same way:

```
List<double> samples = Beta.Samples(alpha, beta).Take(5000).ToList();
```

or

```
double[] samples = new double[5000];
Beta.Samples(samples, alpha, beta);
```

For all of theses variations you can also provide your own Random instance, or [one of those provided by Math.NET Numerics](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Random.html). In case of the class instance you can pass it to the constructor, in case of the static routines there is an overload accepting it as first argument. See [Probability Distributions](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Probability.html) for more details.